# Docker - Cannot checkpoint container

Tags: docker, containers, checkpoint

I am trying to use checkpoint in a busybox image. At first I created a regular loop and then printing the numbers.

```
docker run -d --name simple13 busybox /bin/sh -c "i=0; while true; do echo $i; i=$(expr $i + 1); sleep 1; done"

docker logs -f simple13
```

Then I tried to use checkpoint by following command -

```
docker checkpoint create simple13 checkpoint1
```

But, it shows some error like this -

```
    Error response from daemon: Cannot checkpoint container simple13: 
docker-runc did not terminate sucessfully: CRIU version check failed: exec: 
"criu": executable file not found in $PATH path= 
/var/run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/2fd6f5b517
3fb75ee2793d50602506ee6bc97fcd49df93141846fec21f003be4/criu-dump.log: unknown
```

The experimental is turned on here already. So, can you please inform me what I need to do here to use checkpoint correctly ? Thanks.

```
λ docker version
Client:
 Version:       17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:05:22 2017
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:        Wed Dec 27 20:12:29 2017
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: true
```

Comment: Did you figure out the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You have some problem with the *bash variable expansion*. The way you pass the `CMD` will keep printing empty lines, not numbers. See how the command is finally set to the container (the result is part from `docker container inspect ...` output:

```
"Cmd": [
    "/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    "i=0; while true; do echo ; i=1; sleep 1; done"
],
```

I've changed a little bit the use of quotes and the following prints numbers:

```
docker run -d --name simple13 busybox /bin/sh -c 'i=0; while true; do echo "$i"; i=$(expr "$i" + 1); sleep 1; done'
```

Notice the difference now in the `Cmd` result from `docker container inspect simple13`:

```
"Cmd": [
    "/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    "i=0; while true; do echo \"$i\"; i=$(expr \"$i\" + 1); sleep 1; done"
],
```

**About the `docker checkpoint create simple13 checkpoint1` error:**

For me, it was solved after I used:

```
sudo apt-get install criu
```

But I think, it still doesn't work as it should. Example:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker run -d --name simple13 busybox /bin/sh -c 'i=0; while true; do echo "$i"; i=$(expr "$i" + 1); sleep 1; done'
1ffd1f30aec96e07ac7c229c581b7ccd5feb9d180602eeb663211189abc652e4
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker logs simple13 
0
1
2
3
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker checkpoint create simple13 checkpoint1
checkpoint1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
1ffd1f30aec9        busybox             "/bin/sh -c 'i=0; wh…"   19 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds                           simple13
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker logs simple13 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker checkpoint ls simple13
Error response from daemon: open /var/lib/docker/containers/1ffd1f30aec96e07ac7c229c581b7ccd5feb9d180602eeb663211189abc652e4/checkpoints/checkpoint1/config.json: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Correct. The criu package must be installed on the Docker server.